# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous Use a.any() or a.all() in masked extracting code

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to use a mask to mark the elements in the vector nodes that are in the matrix e. For that I am using a mask for the vector nodes, and trying to set to false the corresponding position, so that at the end I can extract all elements in nodes that are left with a TRUE in the corresponding mask array

```
def SortedInteriorNodes(p,e,t):
    # e is a matrix with two rows, p a matrix with 2 rows, t a matrix with 3 rows
    nn=p.shape[1]  # number of nodes
    nt=t.shape[1]  # number of triangles
    ne=e.shape[1]  # number of edges = number of boundary nodes
    nodes = np.arange(start=0, stop=nn) # 0 1 2 3 ....np-1
    mask = np.full((1, nn), True)
    for col in range(ne):
        for row in range(2):
            k = e[row, col]
            if (mask[k] == True):
                mask[e[row,col]]= False
    # I end up with a vector of boolean where the true indicate the position of Interior Nodes
    InteriorNodes = nodes[mask]
    return InteriorNodes
```

I get this error  "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.  Use a.any() or a.all()"in the line  "if (mask[k] == True):"

I ran the debugger and saw that mask is an array of booleans so mask[k] is a single value not an array so I can't make sense of the error, why would I have to use any or all if I am working with one element at a time not with an array? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this error message.

Comment: I am new to python and those hundred of questions are too complicated I don't think they are showing up for a simple problem like mine

Comment: `mask` is a 2-dimensional array. So `mask[k]` is a row of the array. You can't test if a row is True or False.

Comment: mask= np.full((1, nn), True).  I intended to create a vector of booleans, Why do yu say is 2-dimensional? The debugger shows it's a vector

Comment: You have two dimensions there: `(1, nn)`. If it should be 1-dimensional, use `np.full(nn, True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work, provided that your matrix 'e' only has integers and all integers are nonnegative and less than nn:

```
def SortedInteriorNodes(p,e,t):
    # e is a matrix with two rows, p a matrix with 2 rows, t a matrix with 3 rows
    nn=p.shape[1]  # number of nodes
    nt=t.shape[1]  # number of triangles
    ne=e.shape[1]  # number of edges = number of boundary nodes
    nodes = np.arange(start=0, stop=nn) # 0 1 2 3 ....np-1
    mask = [True] * nn
    for col in range(ne):
        for row in range(2):
            k = e[row, col]
            if (mask[k] == True):
                mask[e[row,col]]= False
    # I end up with a vector of boolean where the true indicate the position of Interior Nodes
    InteriorNodes = nodes[mask]
    return InteriorNodes
```

I changed `mask = np.full((1, nn), True)` to `mask = [True] * nn`.
The reason for the error is that you gave the mask variable two dimensions, (1 row with `nn` columns) rather than 1 dimension. In other words, if `nn` is 3, then you should have made a `mask = [True, True, True]` and instead you made it `[[True, True, True]]`. So when you ask if `mask[0] == True` you are asking it if the first element of mask is equal to `True`. If `mask = [True, True, True]` like I made it, the first element is `True`, which is what you wanted. But if `mask = [[True, True, True]]` like you made it, then the first element is the first row: `[True, True, True]`, which contains three terms. This confuses your program, because the `==` operator compares two elements, and you just tried to compare a list of THREE elements to `True`, which is not allowed.